# How to avoid status bar overlaping content?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am having an issue where the status bar is overlapping the content of my app.

This:
[image]

This is App.js which holds my top level component where I added [SafeAreaView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/safeareaview):

```
     <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
          style={styles.container}
          behavior="padding"
          enabled
        >
          <ReduxProvider store={store}>
            {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
            <AppNavigator />
          </ReduxProvider>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
      </SafeAreaView>
```

That Search bar component you see in the image has a margin:
`<View style={{ marginTop: 22 }}>...` which works properly on the rest of the iOS devices, but not on the new iPhones, like the XR for example which is the device on the screenshot.

So, any ideas on how do I set this margin dynamically so the status bar doesn't overlap the UI content?

Comment: just referenced a recent project that I used this same setup, and the only difference I see in the code is that the first child of `SafeAreaView` has it's style set to `marginTop: 30`

I'm not sure if this will solve your issue or not, just wanted to share my setup. I've since moved on from this project, so it may not actually be helpful to you.

Comment: I have faced this issue recently. I am not sure about your other configurations like router and your index file but putting the SafeAreaView at top level did not work for me. It was working fine at the component level. So to make SafeAreaView available for all the other components I had to create a [high order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) with SafeAreaView in it and I wrapped all other components with the HOC.

Comment: If you're using Expo, try Constants.statusBarHeight for setting a marginTop.